# macOS: Add CalDAV account (Settings/Internet Accounts/CalDAV account) programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-foundation, caldav, accounts

Does anybody know how to programmatically (headless in Objective-C/C++, NOT by using NSAccessibility, AppleScript or any other technology accessing the UI) add a CalDAV account to the macOS system?

Manually this ca be done in System Preferences > Internet Accounts > Add an account > Add Other Account... > CalDAV account.

So far I have only found the Accounts framework, but there are no constants or any other hints how to add/create a CalDAV account.

Regards,
Dominik

Comment: I don’t think there is API for this, but you may be able to add it using a profile.

Comment: Tank you for your answere! What do you mean with "profile"?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Tank you! That works as expected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point there is no API for doing this, but you may be able to add the account using a so called "configuration profile".

To read more about this: [Configuration Profile Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html)